# action bar search view background colour change in expandable

Tags: android

please tell me `enter code here`

```
i need the background colour change in the search view when its expandable but when
```

it is in normal, default background should be there , i tried by changing the height of the layout but no use

please suggest me what is the best approach in this scenario when its in the actionbar

i tried in the theme level also

Comment: http://www.jayway.com/2014/06/02/android-theming-the-actionbar/

Comment: yea but there is also no background color change ,u r also showing the default background color.....

Comment: yea since he didn't do that,  try different "SearchView attributes" defined in the xml